# Why did the Skeksis not kill Aughra?

Tags: dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

The Skeksis trick Aughra into giving them control of the Crystal, in exchange for an orrery. During much of this period, Aughra has essentially been asleep. Yet the Skeksis seem content to leave her to her explorations of the cosmos, instead of eliminating her.

Further, Aughra later awakens. In the interim, the Gelflings have become fanatically devoted to the Skeksis. Apparently suggesting that the latter could be mistaken, dishonest, or malevolent is considered heresy, despite their obviously evil demeanour. Virtually all the Gelflings seem to trust the Skeksis even over their own family. At this point, presumably the Skeksis could simply kill Aughra and make up some story about her death. Yet she can walk in and threaten them, and the worst they do is toss her out of the palace.

So, given their previous eagerness to kill anyone who knew their secrets, why leave Aughra, who knows more than anyone, alive?

Comment: "*...despite their obviously evil demeanour"*? That sounds like anti-Skeksis heresy to me. Seize him!!

Comment: They really do not even try to pretend to be benevolent overlords.  It's an open question as to why the Gelflings like them so much.

Comment: The Skeksis also seem to take pains to hide their murderous rampages. Thra might notice if Aughra died.

Comment: Aughra is linked to the Crystal and Thra. Killing her could have unforeseen consequences and risk the Skeksis whole operation. Plus, it's not clear if Aughra can be killed given the events of the Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance.

https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/Aughra